# Should [heart-failure] be renamed [heart-disease]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I created a tag [heart-failure](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-failure) and upon reflection it probably should have been [heart-disease](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-disease). If the community agrees, I think a moderator should mass edit change (and maybe set heart-failure as a synonym).

I think heart disease is more broad than heart failure, and can cover problems like heart defects and murmurs that may never affect quality of life, but still require monitoring.

Comment: If you haven't already had your say, please vote accordingly or add another 
 answer explaining your viewpoint.

Comment: You don't need to edit all the questions; a mod can create the heart-disease (or whatever) tag by adding it to one question and then merge heart-failure into it.

Answer (score 4):

I agree, the place to vote yes for the tag [heart-disease](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-disease).

Per OP's argument and some conversations in chat.

Comment: The more general term is definitely better in my opinion. It's certainly not a[meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and will apply to more topics than 'heart-failure' would.

Comment: I'd agree with keeping it generalized or the tag will rarely be used... With Heart health being more user friendly or cardiovascular health, a more sesquipedalian word usage

Comment: I favour [tag:heart-disease] for consistency with other tags: [tag:urinary-tract-disease], [tag:eye-disease], [tag:upper-respiratory-disease], etc. Health is really just the absence of disease, but [tag:eye-health] or [tag:upper-respiratory-health] don't really make much sense. [tag:Heart-disease] is generalized to questions about heart problems, but not overtly vague in the way [tag:heart-health] is. There is no reason the 'disease' tags can't include questions about prevention of disease. Either way, I think we should just be consistent in tag names.

Answer (score 4):

We could have

[heart-health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-health) - that should cover all areas of problems.

Update: The [heart-failure](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-failure) has been merged and synonymised with [heart-health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-health)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't heart disease and heart failure two different things? Things that cause heart failure aren't always heart disease, and heart disease doesn't always cause heart failure, at least in my understanding.

Comment: [heart failure causes](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/heart-failure/basics/causes/con-20029801) there are a couple of items on the list that we could debate if there are truly a disease, but heart failure in a pet is likely going to be a postmortem diagnosis (*or a laymen observation*) . What kind of questions might get tagged with heart failure that could be addressed here?  Would tags specific to the underlying cause be more appropriate?

Comment: [Once the dog stops breathing the heart will go into cardiac arrest and cease beating.](http://www.petmd.com/dog/emergency/common-emergencies/e_dg_cardiopulmonary_resuscitation) Other then heart failure secondary to lack of breathing, I don't think there are any events that might be survivable.  Every non-survived event is ultimately a case of the heart failing to circulate oxygen and glucose to the brain.

Comment: Yes, technically that is correct

Comment: @JamesJenkins "heart failure in a pet is likely going to be a postmortem diagnosis" - why? Hunter was diagnosed with heart failure and lived for another 9 months.

Comment: @Zaralynda According to your [post here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8034) Hunter was having "congestive heart failure" (CHF) it is but one of the many typos listed in the link in my first comment.  personally I have always considered everything that happens while you are a live heart insufficiency, failure happens when the heart stops. Maybe my perception is different then everyone else's it happens.

Comment: @JamesJenkins since I was told by the vet he was having congestive heart failure, I don't consider it to be a typo

Comment: @JamesJenkins also, I don't see where in that link that it claims CHF is a typo. HF as defined by the mayo clinic's page is the heart not pumping at full capacity, not that it stops. A pet can live for months like that.

Answer (score -1):

No, but I don't want to post my own answer on why.

The place to vote no.

If you have a better reason and want to share, post it and I will delete this one.

Comment: why not post your own answer on why?

Comment: @YvetteColomb because I couldn't think of one... Just wanted to make sure there was a place to record negative votes, for those not wanting to post an answer.

Comment: I made another couple of suggestions

Comment: I thought the place to record no votes was by voting (down) on the question

Comment: @Zaralynda it could be it, could but there are also several other answers.  It made more sense to me to have a separate place to vote.

Answer (score -1):

We could have

[heart](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart) with a strong wiki that it's any issues to do with the heart.

Answer (score -2):

Another option is:

[heart-conditions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-conditions)